# How to extract the last folder and file name from file path in python

Tags: python-3.x, filepath

I have some filepaths like this:

`G:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\fold2/197320-6-10-0.wav`

How do I extract the last folder and file name like this:

`fold2/197320-6-10-0.wav`

Comment: The `/` is not a legal character in a Windows file name. See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/298607)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is to use `split()` function.

```
text_string = r'''G:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\fold2/197320-6-10-0.wav'''

data = text_string.split("\\")[-1]

print(data)
```

Prints

```
fold2/197320-6-10-0.wav
```